# PHP MYSQLI - Update existing Database with prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$updateData = $con->prepare("UPDATE target SET date=?, time=? WHERE plan_id=?, date=?, time=?");
$updateData->bind_param("iss", $plan_id,$date,$time);
```

As you can see, I am trying to update target table based on date and time to reflect a new date and time. Is it even possible to do so? Or that I have to separate into two separate prepare calls (First Select ID, then update)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the commas in your `WHERE` clause to `AND`'s -

```
$updateData = $con->prepare("UPDATE plandetailmarker 
                             SET date=?, time=? 
                             WHERE plan_id=? 
                               AND placeName=? 
                               AND date=? 
                               AND time=?");
```

You just need to make sure the bound parameters match the number required in the query.

You have 5 items requiring parameters in your query, but you only bind 3

```
$updateData->bind_param("iss", $plan_id,$date,$time);
```

It should be more like this -

```
$updateData->bind_param("ssiss", $date, $time, $plan_id, $date, $time);
```

I strongly suspect your first date and time are different than your second though, so you'll have to call them differently -

```
$updateData->bind_param("ssiss", $new_date, $new_time, $plan_id, $date, $time);
```

Comment: but I am not sure what I'm binding. Issue is that I am trying to set existing date to a new date in the table. It is the same date variable though.

Comment: How can it be the same? A new date *could* be the same, but it isn't likely.

Comment: Ohh I see what you are saying now. I'm going to try it out real quick

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object.

Comment: Inside my Database, plan_id is int(8), rest is varchar.. not sure what is putting it off

Comment: AH! You're using commas instead of `AND` in your `WHERE` clause.